# How to enable HTML5 canvas text in Firefox?

Tags: javascript, html, firefox, canvas

I can see canvas (lines, drawings, etc.), but not canvas text in Firefox profile A.

I'm on Firefox 38.0.5 EME-free on Windows 7. I haven't done anything to the Firefox folder. I can see canvas text on my other profile B.

Here's an example of what I want to be able to see: [HTML canvas fillText() Method](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/canvas_filltext.asp).

- Profile A: the canvas appears as a white rectangle.
- Profile B: I see "Hello World! Big Smile".

I tried `about:config` and searched for "canvas", but the entries were the same in both my profiles.

In [Detecting HTML5 Features - Canvas Text](http://diveintohtml5.info/detect.html#canvas-text), it says:

> Your browser supports the canvas text API

I get these logs in the browser console if I load the w3schools site:

> NS_ERROR_FAILURE: Component returned failure code: 0x80004005 (NS_ERROR_FAILURE) [nsITaskbarTabPreview.invalidate]
>   WindowsPreviewPerTab.jsm:406:0
>
> The character encoding of the HTML document was not declared. The document will render with garbled text in some browser configurations if the document contains characters from outside the US-ASCII range. The character encoding of the page must be declared in the document or in the transfer protocol. 
>   tryit.asp
>
> POST ...w3schoolslink...tags/tryit_view.asp
>   [HTTP/1.1 200 OK 210ms]
>
> The character encoding of a framed document was not declared. The document may appear different if viewed without the document framing it. 
>   tryit_view.asp

And the last two if I click "See Result" on the same w3schools page.

Don't tell me to reset Firefox. I've spent years customizing it just the way I want.

Comment: _“Don't tell me to reset Firefox”_ – when then at least start it with all extensions disabled once (command line option, go look it up), and see if that changes things.

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible that you don't have the used font in both profiles?

I have seen these rectangles as text in cases where I was trying to show "letters" that are not part of the used font. For example I tried to show musical symbols which are defined in unicode, but the most fonts I know don't support them.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. It's possible, I attached logs from the Browser Console that appear to relate to encoding.

Comment: which characters are you trying to draw?

Comment: ctx.font = "20px Georgia";
ctx.fillText("Hello World!", 10, 50);

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_canvas_filltext

Comment: There is no special character which could be a problem under normal circumstances - as far as i know. Sorry in that case I would take a look at your customization of your browser... maybe there is something wrong.

Answer (score 0):

### Preamble

It seems this issue is not present in Firefox 41.0.1.

### Fix1 - TL;DR

Set `gfx.direct2d.disabled` to `false`.

### Fix2 - Alternative

- When `gfx.direct2d.disabled` is `true`
- Set `gfx.canvas.azure.backends` to `cairo`

Using Fix1 has the side effect of botching fonts in webpages and `view-source` (at least for me), while this can be used to keep direct2d disabled while still rendering canvas text.

I tested that after stumbling on this:
[Bug 842521 - PDF.js won't render text when DirectWrite is enabled with both Skia and Cairo backends](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=842521)

### The long answer for Fix1

While this is not really a programming question, in the hope that it gets migrated rather than deleted, I have a possible solution.

I ran into the same issue where my regular Firefox profile would not display canvas text while a fresh profile had no issue. Using safe mode was also ineffective.

Going through preferences in `about:config`, I eventually toggled `gfx.direct2d.disabled` to `false` and text in canvas was then available after restarting the browser.

The likely cause of `gfx.direct2d.disabled` being set to `true` is having disabled hardware acceleration by unchecking `Use hardware acceleration when available` in `Options > Advanced`.

Note that toggling that preference alone will not be considered by Firefox to reenable hardware acceleration, as that only happens when changing the pref `layers.acceleration.disabled`, which has apparently no influence over this issue.